# User permissions in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization

My Rails app is a simple one where users can register and view jobs for a certain organization. I have set up Devise so that users must be authenticated before they can pursue certain actions like viewing jobs, posting jobs, etc. I currently have a job model and a user model. How would I go about setting permissions so that Users can create new posts and ONLY edit and delete the posts that THEY wrote?

```
Job.rb:

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base

# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
# :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable

    devise  :database_authenticatable,
            :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
attr_accessible :contact_email, :contact_phone, :description, :district, :due_date,     :expiration_date, :job_title, :posting_date, :requirements, :salary, :submission_process

end

User.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end

Jobs_Controller.rb:

class JobsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index]


  # GET /jobs
  # GET /jobs.json
  def index
    @jobs = Job.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @jobs }
    end
  end

  # GET /jobs/1
  # GET /jobs/1.json
  def show
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @job }
        end
      end

   # GET /jobs/new
   # GET /jobs/new.json
  def new
    @job = Job.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @job }
    end
  end

  # GET /jobs/1/edit
  def edit
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /jobs
  # POST /jobs.json
  def create
    @job = Job.new(params[:job])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @job.save
        format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @job, status: :created, location: @job }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /jobs/1
  # PUT /jobs/1.json
  def update
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @job.update_attributes(params[:job])
        format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /jobs/1
  # DELETE /jobs/1.json
  def destroy
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    @job.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to jobs_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Have a look at [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).

Answer (score 1):

If you're intending to expand your system and add other roles for example admin, super admin, normal users, guests, ... etc then my advice to you is to have a look at the authentication gem of Ryan Bates which is named [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).

If the app is as simple as you mentioned in your answer, then you've to use the `current_user` method provided by the devise gem also, you've to set a relation between the job and the user. I guess it'll be a one-to-many relation (each user can have many jobs) this can be down by:

1. Create a new migration which adds a column to the `jobs` table, the column name should be `user_id`
2. Add `has_many :jobs` in the user model (user.rb)
3. Add `belongs_to :user` in the job model (job.rb)
4. In your controller the methods edit, update and destroy should be something like that

   ```
     def update
       @job = current_user.jobs.find(params[:id])
       # the rest of the code is omitted 
     end

     def destroy
       @job = current_user.jobs.find(params[:id])
       @job.destroy
       # the rest of the code is omitted 
     end

     def edit
       @job = current_user.jobs.find(params[:id])
     end
   ```

Comment: You should also hide links to edit and destroy in your views when the posts are not the current_user ones.

Answer (score 0):

There's a gem that can help you https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

There's also a screencast demostrating how it works. http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

you can define with cancan what actions a determined user can execute.